# Android - How to retrieve currency exchange rates

Tags: android, currency, finance

I'm trying to develop a simple Forex app for Android.
To start off, I need to get the currency exchange rates, say for the past year.

Could anybody advice how I can go about this?
I looked in Google financh API but couldn't find how to retrieve currency rates.
Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you require real time data or just historical?  If the latter, I'd go with Aleadam's suggestion.. Big question though is, why android?  Why not just create a website with the data you want?  Then wrap it in the thin android application?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the data from the federal reserve. It has historical data separated by country. You can find the link here:

http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h10/Hist/

Data is given in plain ascii, making it very easy to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You could access some Foreign Exchange company APIs and get access to realtime and historical data of a range of currency pairs.

Oanda provide an API : http://fxtrade.oanda.com/trade-forex/api/

Interactive Brokers provide one also : http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=programInterface&p=

XE have a data feed service: http://www.xe.com/ict/

**CurrencyFreaks** provides latest exchange rate for 179 currencies: https://currencyfreaks.com/

Comment: Interactive Broker's API doesn't allow pulling data without it's TWS client open.  I would REALLY doubt it can work on Android alone.. would require a system somewhere to run the TWS client, download info, then feed it to an android device.